# What are things which cannot be done via server side language and only possible with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, usability, accessibility, client-side, server-side

- Is it possible to avoid JavaScript 
  these days for small business
  websites, blogs etc ?
- and is it wise idea?
- What are things which cannot be done
  via server side language and only
  possible with JavaScript? Or is
  everything possible except
  *animation* with server side languages which is possible with
  JavaScript?
- What are reasons in favor of use of
  JavaScript is good for website for
  better functionality, Accessibility,
  SEO and Usability?
- In what scenarios we should use JavaScript always even if thing is also possible with server side language?
- What are common myth about use of Javascript?

Comment: You forgot to ask if it makes good coffee.  :-)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid JavaScript?

Comment: @Stephen C: well, I've not seen JavaScript coffee around...

Comment: @BoltClock - Oh I forgot.  Javascript has nothing to do with Java.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely possible for small businesses, blogs, etc to have sites that do not use any Javascript. It will be difficult to create as strong a user experience, but it can certainly be done. Blogs would be the easiest to do, as there's generally little need for fancy features in a blog.

Basically, the key things that can be done in Javascript that can't be done in server side languages are interactions with the user without additional page reloads. This can certainly create better functionality and increase usability. I'd expect some benefits to accessibility as well. SEO doesn't seem very much a part of it though.

Comment: "Javascript that can't be done in server side languages are interactions with the user without additional page reloads." and i think it's a problem for accessibility.

Comment: and Print page link, Add to bookmark link, live Form validations, text resize Widget are also not possible without javascript.